# php mysql input saves only zero to db

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

```
<div class="control-group invoice-properties">
    <label class="control-label"><?php echo lang('quote_type'); ?></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="quote_type" class="input-small" value="<?php echo $quote->quote_type; ?>" style="margin: 0px;">    
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code is located in a form. When I load the form it retrieves the value from the database. So when I enter directly in the database a number it retrieves this. But when I save it always saves a zero. When I input 8 it makes a 0(zero).

Anyone any idea why this is. Thanks in advance.

Below is the code that does the saving/retrieving at least I think it does.

```
public function save() {
    $this->load->model('quotes/mdl_quote_items');
    $this->load->model('quotes/mdl_quotes');
    $this->load->model('item_lookups/mdl_item_lookups');

    $quote_id = $this->input->post('quote_id');

    $this->mdl_quotes->set_id($quote_id);

    if ($this->mdl_quotes->run_validation('validation_rules_save_quote')) {
        $items = json_decode($this->input->post('items'));

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->item_name) {
                $item->item_quantity = standardize_amount($item->item_quantity);
                $item->item_price    = standardize_amount($item->item_price);

                $item_id = ($item->item_id) ? : NULL;

                $save_item_as_lookup = (isset($item->save_item_as_lookup)) ? $item->save_item_as_lookup : 0;

                unset($item->item_id, $item->save_item_as_lookup);

                $this->mdl_quote_items->save($quote_id, $item_id, $item);

                if ($save_item_as_lookup) {
                    $db_array = array(
                        'item_name'        => $item->item_name,
                        'item_description' => $item->item_description,
                        'item_price'       => $item->item_price
                    );

                    $this->mdl_item_lookups->save(NULL, $db_array);
                }
            }
        }

        $db_array = array(
                'quote_number'       => $this->input->post('quote_number'),
                'quote_type'    => $this->input->post('quote_type'),
                'quote_date_created' => date_to_mysql($this->input->post('quote_date_created')),
                'quote_date_expires' => date_to_mysql($this->input->post('quote_date_expires')),
                'quote_status_id'    => $this->input->post('quote_status_id')
        );

        $this->mdl_quotes->save($quote_id, $db_array);

        $response = array(
                'success' => 1
        );
    } else {
        $this->load->helper('json_error');
        $response = array(
            'success'           => 0,
            'validation_errors' => json_errors()
        );
    }

    if ($this->input->post('custom')) {
        $db_array = array();

        foreach ($this->input->post('custom') as $custom) {
            // I hate myself for this...
            $db_array[str_replace(']', '', str_replace('custom[', '', $custom['name']))] = $custom['value'];
        }

        $this->load->model('custom_fields/mdl_quote_custom');
        $this->mdl_quote_custom->save_custom($quote_id, $db_array);
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

**Edit 1**

The last comments and answers pointed out the name field is not visible. I have uploaded all files that correspond with this to http://websiterheine.eu/quotes.zip

When you look at views/view.php then there are no name fields on any input. But all inputs are correctly working except the one I asked the question about.

Please take a look at the .zip.

**Edit 2**

As pointed out by Patrick a .zip ain't save. So no one will download. Therefore I will post the files on JSFIDDLE. The fiddles wont work because I use it only as a placeholder for the files.

```
**views/view.php**
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ty9f7y9u/

```
**models/mdl_quotes.php**
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4vngkegm/1/

```
**controllers/ajax.php**
```

http://jsfiddle.net/forv452m/1/

```
**controllers/quotes.php**
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1gjc3q6n/

**Edit 3**

I just checked again. There is nowhere in any files $_POST. So it is very strange it is saving all form values.

I have never came across a form like this with no name attributes and no $_POST values. How is this form saving and loading and where is that exactly???

Comment: I think 0 is the default value of field your value is not available on save. Try to print it before save.

Comment: @عثمانغني Thank you for your comment. I don't know what you mean with print before save.

Comment: He means to output the variable to see if it contains what you expect it to.

Comment: print the value of variable which contains value 8

Comment: what is the field name?

Comment: @عثمانغني Thank you there is no field name. When i create a field name i would name it quote_type. Please see the text under Edit 1.

Comment: @patricksweeney I don't know where to output the variable. But shouldn't it be shown in the input box. Please see the files in the .zip.

Comment: Then see the answers. I think your problem should by solved by them

Comment: No one is going to open a strange *.zip from the Web.

Comment: @patricksweeney Any suggestion how I can show all files. They won't fit in the original question. There are 4 files which I think all work together to save and load from the db. I am going to add them in JSFIddle.

Comment: have you tried running the code using the suggestions from answers. You just need to add name in the view file

Comment: use http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: I just added it to jsfiddle. See the links in edit 2. I did not know phpfiddle. I am going to check it out. And yes I have tried the answers. But it is not changing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it with help from someone else wtf8_decode thank you for helping. Also eveyone else thank you.

So the solution was to add in views/view.php the line

```
quote_type: $('#quote_type').val(),
```

to

```
$.post("<?php echo site_url('quotes/ajax/save'); ?>", {
        quote_id: <?php echo $quote_id; ?>,
        quote_number: $('#quote_number').val(),
        quote_date_created: $('#quote_date_created').val(),
        quote_date_expires: $('#quote_date_expires').val(),
        quote_status_id: $('#quote_status_id').val(),
        items: JSON.stringify(items),
        custom: $('input[name^=custom]').serializeArray()
    },
```

So it would look like this:

```
$.post("<?php echo site_url('quotes/ajax/save'); ?>", {
        quote_id: <?php echo $quote_id; ?>,
        quote_number: $('#quote_number').val(),
        quote_type: $('#quote_type').val(),
        quote_date_created: $('#quote_date_created').val(),
        quote_date_expires: $('#quote_date_expires').val(),
        quote_status_id: $('#quote_status_id').val(),
        items: JSON.stringify(items),
        custom: $('input[name^=custom]').serializeArray()
    },
```

Now it is working as it should!

Answer (score 1):

Each form field must have a name to allow you to reference it in your PHP code. In general, you can add a name like this:

```
<input name="your_field_name" type="...
```

Then reference that name in the PHP code that handles your form.

```
$input = $_POST['your_field_name'];
```

Your value will now be saved in `$input` and can be inserted into the database as needed.

In your specific case, your code appears to expect an array of input items, here:

```
$items = json_decode($this->input->post('items'));
```

To make your existing code work with the new change, simply name your field using array syntax:

```
<input name="items[]" type="...
```

Comment: I have updated the question with a .zip with all files that correspond with the form. I can't find "$input = $_POST['your_field_name'];" fields anywhere in those files. But all the other fields are working. It is really confusing.

Comment: 'your_field_name' was given as an example; it will not appear in your form. I have updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: I understood that your_field_name was just an example. What I meant was that there is nowhere in the files $input = $_POST there are no $_POST and that is strange. Because it is saving all the other values. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are missing `name` attribute in your input tag

```
<input type="text" id="quote_type" class="input-small" value="<?php echo $quote->quote_type; ?>" style="margin: 0px;">
```

change this to

```
<input type="text" id="quote_type" name="quote_id" class="input-small" value="<?php echo $quote->quote_type; ?>" style="margin: 0px;">
```

P.S. use of inline CSS in not that good

Comment: Thank you for your answer, If you could please look at the files. Because there are no name attributes by all the other inputs. If there was then I proberly could figure this out on my own. Inline CSS is terible but in this instance a necessity.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<input type="text" id="quote_type" class="input-small" value="<?php echo $quote->quote_type; ?>" style="margin: 0px;">
```

To

```
<input type="text" id="quote_type" name="quote_number" class="input-small" value="<?php echo $quote->quote_type; ?>" style="margin: 0px;">
```

Add the name attribute of input. If your field name is `quote_number` then add `name="quote_number"`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

'<input type="text" id="quote_type" name="quote-type" class="input-small" value="<?php echo $quote->quote_type; ?>" style="margin: 0px;">' Is what i just tried but when i click save it reverts back to zero.